# javascript, prototype can't make own method

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype

I need to get this working, but I dont know why dosent working? Any idea? Thanks for help!

```
(function( window ) {
    function select( selector ) {
        return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    };

    select.prototype.attr = function(atitr)
    {
        return this.getAttribute(atitr);
    };

    window.j = select;
})( window );

console.log(j('.lol:last-child').attr('href'));
```

Comment: `select` is a function in your example. So you're trying to extend prototype of `Function` which hasn't `getAttribute` method

Comment: Is there a specific question here? Are you getting errors in the console? What is the expected output? You've told us nothing about what the code is meant to do.

Comment: You aren't returning an instance of *selector*, even if called with *new* (which it isn't), it returns a NodeList that doesn't inherit from it (and it isn't called with *new* so there is no chance of inheritance).

Comment: js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/axlpl/9eur9bqz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function you have:

```
function select( selector ) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
};
```

so *select* returns a NodeList, which doesn't inherit from *select*. Then there is:

```
window.j = select;
```

and

```
j(...).attr(...)
```

So *select* is called without *new*, so it doesn't create an instance of itself and assign it to *this*. Since that object isn't returned anyway, the returned object won't inherit from *select* even if you do call it with *new*.

#### Edit

You can return an object that has the DOM elements as a property, e.g.:

```
<div class="lol">
  <a href="d" class="lol">sadas11DA</a>
  <a href="d31" class="lol">sadas222DA</a>
</div>

<script>

(function(window) {
  function Select(selector) {
    this.nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }

  Select.prototype.attr = function(attribute) {
  console.log(this.nodes);
    return this.nodes[0]? this.nodes[0].getAttribute(attribute) : null;
  }

  window.j = Select;
}(this))

console.log(new j('.lol:last-child').attr('href'));

</script>
```

Note the modified markup. Also passing of *this* rather than *window* since *this* can't be modified, *window* can.

Comment: ok I got it, but how now I can return only dom element like this: j('.lol'), or this dom element attr like j('.lol').attr('href'); ?

Comment: but what if I dont wanna use new selector before j? I wanna do it in this function, and return, like jQuery do it , jQuery dosent use new $('dsa'); like here

Comment: To use prototype inheritance you have to use *new* or *Object.create*. jQuery calls *new* internally to save typing, e.g. `jQuery = function(...) {return new jQuery.fn.init(...)}`.